# image grabber empty url

Tags: javascript, node.js

urls returns an empty array []

I don't quite understand this part of the code myself as its borrowed,

I either need help understanding the urls part to recode it properly,

or have someone recode it for me which I will try my best to understand.

the urls part was made for google images but Im using another site.

im grabbing images of this site: https://www.desktopnexus.com/search/kitsune+girl/1/

```
function kitsuneimage(message) {
  var options = {
    url: "https://www.desktopnexus.com/search/" + "kitsune+girl" + "/" + Math.ceil(Math.random() * (60 + 2)) +"/",
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      "Accept": "text/html",
      "User-Agent": "Chrome"
    }
  }
  console.log(options.url);

  request(options, function(error, response, responseBody) {
    if (error) {
      return;
    }

    $ = cheerio.load(responseBody);

    var links = $(".image a.link");

    var urls = new Array(links.length).fill(0).map((v, i) => links.eq(i).attr("href"));

    console.log(urls);
    if (!urls.length) {
      return;
    };
    message.channel.send(urls[0]);
  });
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to scrape the url of the images from the website you have mentioned?

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```js
var links = $(".image a.link")
```

maybe this should work:

```js
var thumbnails = $("#middlecolumn .thumbnail")

// this is a jquery object, so we need to call get() to turn it into a plain array
var links = thumbnails.map(thumbnail => thumbnail.parent()).get()

var urls = links.map(link => link.getAttribute('href'))
```

Answer (score 0):

well the thumbnails part does grab the image and it looks like this in the console.log(thumbnails);

```
  '2': {
    type: 'tag',
    name: 'img',
    namespace: 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml',
    attribs: [Object: null prototype] {
      src: '//cache.desktopnexus.com/thumbseg/1853/1853748-200.jpg',
      border: '1',
      alt: 'girl',
      class: 'thumbnail'
    },
```

but it says in the .parent is undefined
I was thinking maybe replace thumbnail with tag since thats the type it is, would that work?

----EDIT----
well thats wrong because thumbnail is the class of the image in this.

so why is .parent undefined?

Answer (score 0):

This question is closed since I moved on to making a new code with "got" module